# How to match objects from list with data from map with condition and save to another map using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Looking for solution how to match objects from list with data from map with condition if object field starts with map values and save to another map

i have map with some data

```
Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap()
    dataMap.put("d1", "DATA1")
    dataMap.put("d2", "DATA2")
    dataMap.put("d3", "DATA3")
```

and list of DataElement objects

```
    List<DataElement> elements = new ArrayList()

elements.add(new DataElement("TEXT1"))
elements.add(new DataElement("TEXT2"))
elements.add(new DataElement("DATA1_text1"))
elements.add(new DataElement("DATA2_text2"))


class DataElement {
            public field;


        public DataElement(String text){
            this.field = text
        }

        public getField(){
            return this.field
        }


    }
```

And i'am trying to get new Map where keys are values from first map and values are objects(field) from List with condition if object field starts with map value:
Result should be:

```
[d1=DATA1_text1, d2=DATA2_text2]
```

My code:

```
    Map<String, String> collect2 = dataMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter({ map -> elements.stream()
                                .anyMatch({ el -> el.getField().startsWith(map.getValue()) })})
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(KEY, VALUE))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I got the question right:

```
Map<String, String> collect2 = 
    dataMap.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .map(e -> elements.stream()
                            // this will search for the first element of the List matching
                            // the value of the current Entry, if exists
                            .filter(el -> el.getField().startsWith(e.getValue()))
                            .findFirst()
                            // this will create a new Entry having the original key and the
                            // value obtained from the List
                            .map(el -> new SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(),el.getField()))
                            // if findFirst found nothing, map to a null element
                            .orElse(null))
          .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter out all the nulls
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

You are processing the entries of the input `Map`, and keep only entries having a value that matches an element of the `List` (via `filter()`, though you have some syntax errors), but you need to `map` the input entries into new entries that contain the desired new value.

This above code produces the `Map`

```
{d1=DATA1_text1, d2=DATA2_text2}
```

for the given input.

Comment: Get an exception: Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3.filter() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [false]

Comment: @jhenya-d I have to admint that I tested this code without the `DataElement` class, which I didn't have. I replaced it with `String`, and replaced each `el.getField()` with `el`. That worked fine for me. Can you include the code of the `DataElement` class?

Comment: @jhenya-d And regarding `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException` - are you programming in Java or in Groovy? The question was tagged java, and I'm not familiar with Groovy.

Comment: one moment i'll check

Comment: When using `.flatMap(e -> elements.stream() .filter(…) .limit(1) .map(…))` you get the same logic, without `… findFirst() … .orElse(null)) .filter(Objects::nonNull)`